# how check if username in java desktop application is already exists

Tags: java, database

I have already made java desktop application 
which is stored data into database
but I want to know if I can check if the name which I want to insert into database is already exists or not  like website
thanks for your help

Comment: Your question is very unclear. I suggest you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rephrase your question. Otherwise you will get a lot of downvotes and NO answers.

Comment: Just query the database. ```select count(*) from user where username=?``` If the result is 0, then it's free.

Comment: Search the database for the name.  Or make the name column unique and listen for the DB to reject the duplicate when you attempt to insert it.